# On starting my MVC3 application, getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, stack-overflow

I can't capture what is happening here.  My global.asax file has nothing exotic in it, but I simply cannot start my MVC3 application on my local IIS Express server now:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Paginate",
            "{controller}/Paginate/{itemsPerPage}/{pageNumber}/{searchPhrase}", //URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Paginate", itemsPerPage = Configuration.DefaultPageSize, pageNumber = 1, searchPhrase = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { itemsPerPage = @"\d+", pageNumber = @"\d+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

The exception is captured at `RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);` but if I comment it out it will happen at `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`.  If I comment both out, it happens at `RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`.  How do I even troubleshoot this?  I can't put in a breakpoint that will catch!

**Update:** here are the call stacks I am capturing:

This is from having all three enabled:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() + 0x5 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() + 0x4f bytes 
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.FilterTypesInAssemblies(System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager, System.Predicate<System.Type> predicate) + 0xa5 bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(string cacheName = "MVC-AreaRegistrationTypeCache.xml", System.Predicate<System.Type> predicate, System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager = {System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper}) + 0x40 bytes  
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes = Count = Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state., System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager, object state = null) + 0x57 bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(object state) + 0x2e bytes  
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() + 0x7 bytes   
>GHM.DFP.AdminUI.DLL!GHM.DFP.AdminUI.MvcApplication.Application_Start() Line 36 C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.InvokeMethodWithAssert(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, int paramCount, object eventSource, System.EventArgs eventArgs) + 0x3c bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ProcessSpecialRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, int paramCount, object eventSource, System.EventArgs eventArgs, System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState session) + 0xef bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}, System.Web.HttpApplication app) + 0x13e bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(System.IntPtr appContext = 723127104, System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}, System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] handlers) + 0x84 bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(System.Web.HttpApplicationState state, System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] handlers, System.IntPtr appContext = 723127104, System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0xc3 bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(System.IntPtr appContext, System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x154 bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(System.IntPtr appContext = 723127104) + 0xfe bytes  
[Appdomain Transition]  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
webengine4.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x3740 bytes 
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for webengine4.dll]    
webengine4.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x47e bytes  
iiscore.dll!01d328cd()  
iiscore.dll!01d1a777()  
iiscore.dll!01d33247()  
iiscore.dll!01d334c2()  
iiscore.dll!01d25d67()  
iiscore.dll!01d26196()  
iiscore.dll!01d2686c()  
iiscore.dll!01d26d04()  
w3dt.dll!HTTP_WRAPPER::QueryState()  + 0x17fc bytes 
w3dt.dll!HTTP_WRAPPER::QueryState()  + 0x23 bytes   
w3tp.dll!THREAD_POOL::PostCompletion()  + 0xd6 bytes    
w3tp.dll!THREAD_POOL::TerminateThreadPool()  + 0xa5 bytes   
w3tp.dll!0f311f55()     
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()  + 0xef bytes   
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()  + 0xc2 bytes
```

I disable `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` and this is what I get:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() + 0x5 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() + 0x4f bytes 
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.FilterTypesInAssemblies(System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager, System.Predicate<System.Type> predicate) + 0xa5 bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(string cacheName = "MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml", System.Predicate<System.Type> predicate, System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager = {System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper}) + 0x40 bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ControllerTypeCache.EnsureInitialized(System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager) + 0x80 bytes 
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces(System.Web.Routing.RouteBase route = {System.Web.Routing.Route}, string controllerName = "Home", System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string> namespaces = null) + 0x4d bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) + 0x234 bytes 
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.GetControllerSessionBehavior(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext = {System.Web.Routing.RequestContext}, string controllerName) + 0x3e bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) + 0x7d bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext = {System.Web.Routing.RequestContext}) + 0x2a bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) + 0xb bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(System.Web.HttpContextBase context = {System.Web.HttpContextWrapper}) + 0x108 bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x57 bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x95 bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step = {System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep}, ref bool completedSynchronously = false) + 0x4c bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x39f bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb) + 0x5a bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr = {System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest}, System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}) + 0xbe bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext = 730752100, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x247 bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x29 bytes    
webengine4.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x19b7 bytes 
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for webengine4.dll]    
webengine4.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x25e8 bytes 
webengine4.dll!MgdGetServerVariableA()  + 0x2fd6 bytes  
webengine4.dll!MgdGetServerVariableA()  + 0x3485 bytes  
iiscore.dll!005f086a()  
iiscore.dll!005f1724()  
iiscore.dll!005de053()  
iiscore.dll!005e0779()  
iiscore.dll!005e2cd6()  
iisfreb.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x1870 bytes    
iiscore.dll!005e0f63()  
webengine4.dll!MgdReleaseNativeConfigSystem()  + 0x9e bytes 
webengine4.dll!MgdIndicateCompletion()  + 0x24 bytes    
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x2cc bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x29 bytes    
[Appdomain Transition]  
webengine4.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x19b7 bytes 
webengine4.dll!MgdGetServerVariableA()  + 0x2cc0 bytes  
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()  + 0xef bytes   
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()  + 0xc2 bytes
```

Commenting out `RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)` gets me this:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() + 0x5 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() + 0x4f bytes 
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.FilterTypesInAssemblies(System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager, System.Predicate<System.Type> predicate) + 0xa5 bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(string cacheName = "MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml", System.Predicate<System.Type> predicate, System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager = {System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper}) + 0x40 bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ControllerTypeCache.EnsureInitialized(System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager) + 0x80 bytes 
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces(System.Web.Routing.RouteBase route = {System.Web.Routing.Route}, string controllerName = "Home", System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string> namespaces = null) + 0x4d bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) + 0x234 bytes 
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.GetControllerSessionBehavior(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext = {System.Web.Routing.RequestContext}, string controllerName) + 0x3e bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) + 0x7d bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext = {System.Web.Routing.RequestContext}) + 0x2a bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) + 0xb bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(System.Web.HttpContextBase context = {System.Web.HttpContextWrapper}) + 0x108 bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x57 bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x95 bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step = {System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep}, ref bool completedSynchronously = false) + 0x4c bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x39f bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb) + 0x5a bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr = {System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest}, System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}) + 0xbe bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext = 730145292, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x247 bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x29 bytes    
webengine4.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x19b7 bytes 
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for webengine4.dll]    
webengine4.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x25e8 bytes 
webengine4.dll!MgdGetServerVariableA()  + 0x2fd6 bytes  
webengine4.dll!MgdGetServerVariableA()  + 0x3485 bytes  
iiscore.dll!0fcd086a()  
iiscore.dll!0fcd1724()  
iiscore.dll!0fcbe053()  
iiscore.dll!0fcc0779()  
iiscore.dll!0fcc2cd6()  
iisfreb.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x1870 bytes    
iiscore.dll!0fcc0f63()  
webengine4.dll!MgdReleaseNativeConfigSystem()  + 0x9e bytes 
webengine4.dll!MgdIndicateCompletion()  + 0x24 bytes    
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x2cc bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x29 bytes    
[Appdomain Transition]  
webengine4.dll!RegisterModule()  + 0x19b7 bytes 
webengine4.dll!MgdGetServerVariableA()  + 0x2cc0 bytes  
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()  + 0xef bytes   
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()  + 0xc2 bytes
```

Comment: And if you comment all three?

Comment: View the stack trace when the exception occurs, that way you can track down what is happening.  Perhaps, even post it here so it can be used to better help you out.

Comment: I believe the `System.StackOverflowException` is the only exception not handled by this website.

Comment: this smells like it might be happening in a static constructor. Are you doing anything fishy in defining `Configuration.DefaultPageSize` ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez, how do I view the stack trace?  It looks like this is happening before the debugger can attach to the process; certainly before I can trap it.

Comment: @bhamlin, the Configuration.DefaultPageSize is a static property that reads once from the web.config and then stores the value in memory.  Can't see how that could possibly cause this.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, if I comment all three out, I do not get the exception, but I do get a 404.20 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately gave up on this after about 6 hours of frustration.  I ported all my code into a new MVC application, and it worked.  Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the same error even with new MVC 3 application template. So, I i re-installed MVC 3 and MVC 3 tools for Visual Studio 2010. It's working for me now.

I installed service pack for Visual Studio 2010, maybe the installation had something to do with exception